# Flutter Web Firebase storage error response storage/unkown

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

hope all is well.

I have been trying to upload an image or file to firebase storage from flutter web. Once I try to call put data the console just reads

```
Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)
```

I don't know how to check server response when using a plugin but this error comes from the try-catch block with on firebaseexception print error

```
Code: XFile? pickedImage;
  _startFilePicker() async {
    pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      imageQuality: 60,
      maxWidth: 250,
    );
    setState(() {
      _hasUploaded = true;
    });

    uploadImageToStorage(pickedImage);
  }

  String uploadedPhotoUrl = '';
  uploadImageToStorage(XFile? pickedFile) async {
    try {
      final String url = FirebaseStorage.instance.bucket;

      Reference _reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .refFromURL(
              'gs://genderbasedviolence-bd860.appspot.com/') //${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}
          .child('images');
      final bytes = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();
      await _reference.putData(bytes);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
    }
  }
```

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks

Comment: Have you followed the official docs? https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage I don't think you need to pass the ref URL like that or even all along

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both ways with the same error. Tried with just ref() leaving it empty and reffromurl